# Substituing equation on Sympy

Tags: python, optimization, typeerror, sympy

I'm trying to make an substitution of an equation to another, to reduce the variables.

Ex:

```
Import sympy


r, h = sympy.symbols('r h')


volume = sympy.Eq(sympy.pi*r**2*h , 355)
areaSup = 2*sympy.pi*r*h + 2*sympy.pi*r**2
areaSup = areaSup.subs(h, volume)
```

Give me an error:

```
TypeError: Relational can not be used in Mul
```

But if I rewrite the equation on subs, this pass.

I don't know how to solve this kind of problem, rewrite formulas every time is key to error.

Answer (score 0):

`h` should be replaced by the value of `h` you get when *solving* the area-equation for `h`:

```py
>>> areaSup.subs(h, solve(volume,h)[0])
2*pi*r**2 + 710/r
```

Comment: Why you use [0]? Because without this goes wrong.

Comment: `solve` returns a list of solutions. The `[0]` selects the first (and only) solution for this linear equation.